# "Voyager: Lightning on Jupiter": what's a sound source for this?

Tags: space, nasa

NASA created an official [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/nasa/) channel with a various sounds from missions.

There are a [Voyager: Lightning on Jupiter](https://soundcloud.com/nasa/voyager-lightning-on-jupiter?in=nasa/sets/solar-system-beyond-sounds) sound.

Is there are ay information on how's this sound is produced (and other like this)?

I tried to seek in Google and NASA sites, but haven't found anything reasonable so far.

Comment: You can just "sonify" the data, as discussed [here](http://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/more-than-meets-the-eye-nasa-scientists-listen-to-data/index.html#.VLa_alprnlL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, it's an easy matter to turn a one dimensional measurement that is sampled over time to sound. For example, electromagnetic field strength versus time. It's even easier to convert a time-varying spectrum (frequency and intensity) to sound. That's what this "lightning on Jupiter" sound track represents. The Voyager Plasma Wave System sampled the strength of the electromagnetic field at various radio frequencies. The result was a frequency and intensity pair indexed by time. This is so very easy to represent as sound.

This conversion is the auditory equivalent of data visualization. Just as our eyes are very good at seeing patterns, our ears are very good at hearing patterns in sound.